# Wrong command using sed, in more folders, listed with grep

Tags: php, bash, vim, sed

Here my script to do refactorging with PHP. I've created a command that works inside vim, but only inside a folder.

```
!for i in `grep -Rl OldName foldername/`; do sed -i 's/OldName/NewName/g' $i; done;
```

What I am asking here, is the update to this script, that allow me to run sed in more folders, with one single command. I've tried this:

```
!for i in `grep -Rl OldName .{a,b,c}/`; do sed -i 's/OldName/NewName/g' $i; done;
```

But does not works. Can some one suggest me the fix?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `find` and `sed` like this:

```
find {src,test,scripts} -type f -exec sed -i 's/OldName/NewName/g' {} +
```

`find` command will find all the files in folders `src,test,scripts` in *current directory* and `sed` will perform inline substitution.

Comment: folders are `src`, `test` and `scripts`. Can you fix your regexp for this purpose?

Comment: {} represents reach file found by find command and + is delimiter for the exec command. Also check `man find` for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(grep -Rl OldName src/ test/ scripts/); do sed -i 's/OldName/NewName/g' "$i" ; done;
```

You can give a list of directories to search as shown above. like `src/` `test/` `scripts/` .